# Problem making slide content appear - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I took this code and I'm trying to make a slide carousel in which 2 slides appear. The problem is that I can't make the two slides appear in sequence. Only the second appears.

What I'm in doubt is at the end of the code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlineArrowRight } from "react-icons/ai";
import { sliderData } from "./slider-data";
import styles from "./Slider.module.scss";
import Imagem1 from '../../public/images/imagem_youtube.png'
import Imagem2 from '../../public/images/imagem_youtube.png'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Slider = () => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const slideLength = sliderData.length;

  const autoScroll = true;
  let slideInterval;
  let intervalTime = 5000;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentSlide(currentSlide === slideLength - 1 ? 0 : currentSlide + 1);
    console.log("next");
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrentSlide(currentSlide === 0 ? slideLength - 1 : currentSlide - 1);
    console.log("prev");
  };

  function auto() {
    slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentSlide(0);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (autoScroll) {
      auto();
    }
    return () => clearInterval(slideInterval);
  }, [currentSlide]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.slider}>
      <AiOutlineArrowLeft className={styles.arrow_prev} onClick={prevSlide} />
      <AiOutlineArrowRight className={styles.arrow_next} onClick={nextSlide} />
      {sliderData.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={index === currentSlide ? "slide current" : "slide"}
            key={index}
          >
            {index === currentSlide && (
              <div>
                <Image src={Imagem1} alt="slide" className={styles.image} />
                <div className={styles.content}>
                  <h2>Slide One</h2>
                  <p>This is the description of slide one Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quos quas, voluptatum nesciunt illum exercitationem.</p>
                  <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 1</button>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              </div>) && (
              <div>
              <Image src={Imagem2} alt="slide" className={styles.image} />
              <div className={styles.content}>
                <h2>Slide Two</h2>
                <p>This is the description of slide one Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quos quas, voluptatum nesciunt illum exercitationem.</p>
                <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 2</button>
                <hr />
              </div>
            </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

I took this code and I'm trying to make a slide carousel in which 2 slides appear. The problem is that I can't make the two slides appear in sequence. Only the second appears.

What I'm in doubt is at the end of the code

Comment: your code only allows showing one `slide`, it's matching the `index` with `currentSlide` and it'll show the `slide` which satisfies the condition.

Comment: You are using the short circuit `&&` operator in sequence and the value of the third and last operand is the only one that has a chance to run. That final JSX renders slide 2 even when your index matches 0. I would remove the last `&&` and accompanying JSX coming after it. The bigger issue is that you are explicitly writing in each slide's data. You need to keep each slide's data in state. Once you clean up the conditional rendering, then you'll only need to return one slide "view" in your render which will get passed the data for the current slide from state.

Comment: @abgregs, Got it, but how do I put the each slide's data in state?

Comment: @abgregs I wanted to leave it that way because I'm going to put a modal after clicking the button. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make a slide carousel in which 2 slides appear. The
> problem is that I can't make the two slides appear in sequence.

Below is an answer that addresses a minimal representation of your problem.

Your other question about creating a modal is outside the scope of your original question. You can certainly add a modal. I'd recommend researching some examples on the web or previous SO questions on the topic first.

Hopefully the answer helps.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const initialSlides = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'slide 1',
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/800/e2639c',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'slide 2',
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/800/ea9999',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'slide 3',
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/800/af7ba9',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'slide 4',
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/800/4c5d6e',
  },
];

const Slider = () => {
  const [slides, setSlides] = useState(initialSlides);
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  const { id, title, imageUrl } = slides[slideIndex];

  const handlePrevSlide = () => {
    const newIndex = slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex - 1 : slides.length - 1;
    setSlideIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const handleNextSlide = () => {
    const newIndex = slideIndex < slides.length - 1 ? slideIndex + 1 : 0;
    setSlideIndex(newIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlePrevSlide}>Prev</button>
      <div style={{ padding: '40px', backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}>
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: '#ffffff' }}>{title}</h2>
        <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: '#ffffff' }}>slide id: {id}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleNextSlide}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

Comment: @Mpimenta Sure thing. If it helped solve your issue feel free to mark it as useful/accepted.